# Hugo academic "render of page failed" and exit with code 225

Tags: html, netlify, hugo, personalization

I'm trying to use hugo academic to build a personal website. When I moved&created some folders yesterday on Netlify, it didn't work anymore. The initialization is successful but the build section always sucks. The log is shown below:

```
11:37:43 AM: hugo: collected modules in 3825 ms
11:37:43 AM: Start building sites …
11:37:43 AM: hugo v0.111.3-5d4eb5154e1fed125ca8e9b5a0315c4180dab192+extended linux/amd64 BuildDate=2023-03-12T11:40:50Z VendorInfo=gohugoio
11:37:44 AM: ERROR 2023/07/23 03:37:44 render of page failed: /opt/build/cache/hugo_cache/modules/filecache/modules/pkg/mod/github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-themes/modules/wowchemy/v5@v5.7.1-0.20230420205746-951c7b6f709d/layouts/project/single.html:5:5: execute of template failed: template: project/single.html:5:5: executing main at <partial page_header.html .>: error calling partial: /opt/build/cache/hugo_cache/modules/filecache/modules/pkg/mod/github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-themes/modules/wowchemy/v5@v5.7.1-0.20230420205746-951c7b6f709d/layouts/partials/page_header.html:70:5: execute of template failed: template: partials/page_header.html:70:5: executing partials/page_header.html at <partial page_links_div.html $page>: error calling partial: /opt/build/cache/hugo_cache/modules/filecache/modules/pkg/mod/github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-themes/modules/wowchemy/v5@v5.7.1-0.20230420205746-951c7b6f709d/layouts/partials/page_links_div.html:10:5: execute of template failed: template: partials/page_links_div.html:10:5: executing partials/page_links_div.html at <partial page_links (dict page . is_list 0)>: error calling partial: /opt/build/cache/hugo_cache/modules/filecache/modules/pkg/mod/github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-themes/modules/wowchemy/v5@v5.7.1-0.20230420205746-951c7b6f709d/layouts/partials/page_links.html:136:17: execute of template failed: template: partials/page_links.html:136:17: executing partials/page_links.html at <.icon_pack>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.icon_pack

11:37:44 AM: Total in 4833 ms
11:37:44 AM: ​
11:37:44 AM: build.command failed                                        
11:37:44 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:37:44 AM: ​
11:37:44 AM:   Error message
11:37:44 AM:   Command failed with exit code 255: hugo --gc --minify -b $URL (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-255)
11:37:44 AM: ​
11:37:44 AM:   Error location
11:37:44 AM:   In build.command from netlify.toml:
11:37:44 AM:   hugo --gc --minify -b $URL
11:37:44 AM: ​
11:37:44 AM:   Resolved config
11:37:44 AM:   build:
11:37:44 AM:     command: hugo --gc --minify -b $URL
11:37:44 AM:     commandOrigin: config
11:37:44 AM:     environment:
11:37:44 AM:       - HUGO_VERSION
11:37:44 AM:       - HUGO_ENABLEGITINFO
11:37:44 AM:       - HUGO_ENV
11:37:44 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/public
11:37:44 AM:     publishOrigin: config
11:37:44 AM:   plugins:
11:37:44 AM:     - inputs:
11:37:44 AM:         debug: true
11:37:44 AM:       origin: config
11:37:44 AM:       package: netlify-plugin-hugo-cache-resources
11:37:45 AM: Caching artifacts
```

I guessed the problem is due to the name of images added, so I tried to delete new images and renamed them "featured.jpg". But it didn't work. I also change the version from 0.111.3 to 0.111.0 and enabled "extent = true"